# Problems reading special characters from word document using office interop in C#

Tags: ms-word, office-interop

I'm trying to read text from a word .DOC using  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word

The text has some temperature degrees e.g.  95°F.
When I get the string from Range.Text, it becomes 95(F

Here is the C# code:

```
private Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application _wordApp;

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document  wordDocument 
                                   = _wordApp.Documents.Open(fileName, false, true);

for (int tableCounter = 1; tableCounter <= wordDocument.Tables.Count; tableCounter++)
{
    var inputTable = wordDocument.Tables[tableCounter];

    for (int cellCounter = 1; cellCounter <= inputTable.Range.Cells.Count; cellCounter++)
    {
        var problemText = inputTable.Range.Cells[cellCounter].Range.Text;
    }
}
```